# How to create a new list for each iteration of for loop in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I want to create a new list each time a for loop runs. And I want to name them based on a character vector. Currently this is how the code goes:

```
for (c in my_vector){
    x <- DBI:dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=query)
    filename <- x[ ,c(3)]
    my_list <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(filename)){
         y <- DBI:dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=query2)
         name <- filename[i]
         tmp <- list(y)
         my_list[[name]] <- tmp
     }
}
```

I want to create a separate/new list for each element of my_vector and then fill the list elements with another for loop.
However, current code overwrites this list and it only saves data from last iteration of for loop.
Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Put them all in a bigger list. And don't use `c`, the name of the most common R function, as a variable unless you **really** need to.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I won't use `c` in the for loop. I don't want to create a big list. my_vector contains list of datasets, therefore I want to be able to create a separate list for each dataset and list would contain analysis corresponding to that dataset.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use the big list as a big list, it can be a nice way to create and name the objects, and then you can use `list2env(big_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)` to put the big list items into your global environment (or any other environment) with appropriate names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will produce lists equal to the length of `my_vector` having names `my_list_v1` , `my_list_v2` and so on, where v1 ,v2 , .... are the elements of `my_vector`

```
for (c in my_vector){
    x <- DBI:dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=query)
    filename <- x[ ,c(3)]
    my_list <- paste0("my_list" ,"_", c)
    l <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(filename)){
         y <- DBI:dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement=query2)
         name <- filename[i]
         tmp <- list(y)
         l[[name]] <- tmp
     }
     assign( my_list , value = l)
}
```